# Image doesn't display at the first visit, but display when tap inspect on console

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5.2, ruby-2.3

I am making a communication app in Rails, but I have encountered a strange bug.
Image dosen't display at the first visit on specific page.

[bug photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g2SwD.png) & [no bug photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FghN8.png)

**Detail**

The Bug occurs only at the first visit on this page.
After the bug occurs, if do the following things, image will be displayed normally.

1. Visit the page again via another page
2. Update the page
3. Tap "select an element in the page to inspect it" on chrome console.(very strange)

**Solution**

If set "data-turbolinks = 'false'" to "a tag" before visit the page, images will be displayed without the bug, but I want to keep turbolinks.
Is there anyone has a solution?

Comment: Both of your links (bug and no bug) showing photo for me without any problem. Try to reset your browser and application cache, try to reproduce bug in other browsers and in incognito mode in Chrome.

Comment: Do you use some js code for image displaying? If yes, add it to the question, please

Comment: @Oleksii Baidan
I reset browser and cashe, and check incognito mode, but the bug was still remain. I have resolved by my self. Thank you!

Comment: @Vasilisa I didn't use js code to display the image that bug occurred. I proceeded the verification and have resolved by my self. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I didn't fix the cause of the bug, so it can not be said to be a solution, but I have relolved it with another way.

I surveyed mainly on javascript and the result was as follows.

- Bug disappear if turn off javascript on browser.
- Even if all javascript files other than applocation.js are deleted,
  the bug remains.

After all I felt like the cause was turbolinks, but I didn't want to turn off turbolonks, so I continued the investigation.
I proceeded the verification based on a strange event that fix the bug when tap "select an element in the page to inspect it" of chrome console.

And I found the bug was fixed that it was not only to tap that part, but also when switching(show / hide) the console itself.(Verified with chrome and safari)

I  resized the window as a test when the bug occurred, the bug was fixed.
I added a js code that resize width a bit when visit the page. The bug isn't occurred so far.